# How to version middle tier .NET application classes/methods

Tags: c#, .net, versioning, asp.net-web-api2

We have a typical N-Layer .NET application which sits in between our database and Web API service layer. This application consists of Business Layer, Data Repository/Access along with the related DTOs and Business Objects.

We have solutions in place to version our stored procedures and our Web API endpoints. The issue is the solution to version this middle layer, the actual class methods and schema objects. All Google searches come up with results for versioning source code in a source control solution or how to version using the Assembly info, neither of these are what we are referring to so results are limited.

So for example, we have two endpoints:

...api/v1/tax/charges 
...api/v2/tax/charges

v1 must hit one version of the method CalculateTaxPctgs and v2 hits another version with updated business logic. Along with both needing to use different versions of the POCO Tax and TaxItems as we changed the name of one field in v2.

The easy to develop but hard to manage and very rigid/static solution would be to create two different methods, CalculateTaxPctgs_V1 and CalculateTaxPctgs_V2. This doesn't seem like a good idea.

Hard to find best practices or even alternative solutions for this dilemma. This is an enterprise application which takes millions of requests every day so performance is extremely important but so is code management and reliability.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of different methods I'd use object inheritance. This way if a method stays the same between different versions you don't need to change the implementation in any way. You could then use a factory of some sort to create the instance required. For example:

```
public virtual class TaxCalculatorBase {
    public virtual ICollection<TaxPercentage> CalculateTaxPercentages() {
        DefaultImplementation();
    }
}

public sealed class TaxCalculatorV1 : TaxCalculatorBase {
    //Same implementation so no need to override
}

public sealed class TaxCalculatorV2 : TaxCalculatorBase {
    //Same implementation but with a bit extra
    public override ICollection<TaxPercentage> CalculateTaxPercentages() {
        base.CalculateTaxPercentages();
        ExtraStuff();
    }
}

public sealed class TaxCalculatorV3 : TaxCalculatorBase {
    //Different implementation
    public override ICollection<TaxPercentage> CalculateTaxPercentages() {
        NewImplementation();
    }
}

public static class TaxCalculatorFactory {
    public static TaxCalculatorBase Create(int version) {
        switch (version) {
            case 1: return new TaxCalculatorV1;
            case 2: return new TaxCalculatorV2;
            case 3: return new TaxCalculatorV3;
            default: throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }
}

public class CallingClass {
    public void CallingMethod(int versionFromURL) {
        var calculator = TaxCalculatorFactory.Create(versionFromURL);
        var percentages = calculator.CalculateTaxPercentages();
        percentages.DoStuffWithThem();
    }
}
```

If the api implements an entire new version each time the factory can be more generic and something like:

```
public static class MyFactory {
    public static TaxCalculatorBase CreateTaxCalculator(int version) {
            switch (version) {
                case 1: return new TaxCalculatorV1;
                case 2: return new TaxCalculatorV2;
                case 3: return new TaxCalculatorV3;
                default: throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }
    }
    //various other methods to create classes which depend on version
}
```

Comment: How do you handle argument type/count changes within versions ?

Comment: Why all versions of TextCalculator inherited from TextCalculatorBase object?You need to write some methods again such as if v1 has method get() , v2 has method get()  and get() methods exactly same for v1 and v2. if you use v2 : v1 like vn:vn-1 inheritance can be better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this depends on exactly how your solution is put together but would redirecting assembly versions be something you could leverage :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> You can redirect your app to use a different version of an assembly in a number of ways: through publisher policy, through an app configuration file; or through the machine configuration file.

Comment: As stated, its a web api application so we would need to interrogate the request, identify the version and dynamically load a different set of assemblies. We have thought about this but we can't use app or machine config since its dynamic. Really looking for a real world implementation of this if this is the best route, we are concerned about performance with dynamic load on application that gets millions of requests a day. Have you used this or just suggesting it?

Comment: I've not used it in this context - and can't offer you a real world implementation.  It just felt like it might offer a solution.  Failing that - I'd probably go with a, non standard, dynamic load (probably using a directory structure based on the version number).  Sorry can't be of more help.  Good luck anyway though.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem we have implemented dynamically loading assemblies which handles over 80 different versions.  It works well.  We don't change the deployed software (unless there is a serious flaw) since it's part of a production system that we can't afford to break once it works.

We also have some critical changes over time, like using several different versions of .NET.  To handle this we route requests to different application deployments.

Comment: I'm intrigued, can you elaborate on this implementation of dynamic assembly loading that you use? What type of application and at what point in your application do you load the correct assemblies? Where are the assemblies located? And how do you manage the different versions, both in naming scheme and how you map the correct assembly versions to each version of the application?

Comment: Keith - do you have any specifics regarding your implementation?